# Compiling in Linux&Eclipse when I can compile from terminal

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, debugging, makefile

So I was finally able to download an old version of webkit and compile it (after fixing 100 errors) in the terminal using the classic:

```
./configure
make
```

Now since I have the source of the program, my goal is to debug it (setting breakpoints on the C++ code and stuff). Since I'm using Linux for the first time here I downloaded eclipse to have an intuitive GUI. However, when I import the project I can't seem to be able to compile it. Include errors are everywhere and I cannot solve them no matter how much I try.

How can I compile it in eclipse when I can do it in the terminal? Also, is there another approach to debug the program?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you create a "Makefile Project with Existing Code"? That always works for me if there's a working makefile.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use gdb https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Comment: @MikeSeymour No I didn't, I found instructions on the web to create an empty project from the source directory. I will search for those instructions now, thanks!

Comment: @RobKielty Can I run the webkitgtk executable and import the sources in some way? I think gdb should need the sources **and** debug symbols and I've no idea how to generate debug symbols in Linux using the terminal. I'm a Visual studio guy sadly.

Comment: Symbol generation done at compile time so it is likely that the build process can enable/disable symbol generation.

Comment: @RobKielty so you're telling me there's a generic way to generate symbols using the make command? I'll search for that. Don't really know how to import them into gdb afterwards but I'll probably manage

Comment: Typically it is done via options on a compiler such as gcc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72255/discussion-between-rob-kielty-and-damieh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I managed to compile and link the code so that it could be loaded into gdb with symbolic debugging info as follows :

1. I downloaded and extracted http://webkitgtk.org/releases/webkitgtk-2.0.4.tar.xz
2. I ran ./configure and manually did `apt-get install` (or in the case of ICU downloaded and compiled) all required dependencies.
3. I then made the following modifications to the `GNUmakefile` adding `-ggdb`
   to each of the vairable `global_cppflags`  `global_cflags` and `global_cxxflags` (In an effort to speed up the build I removed all warning flags from the cppflags, not sure it made a difference. You should probably reinstate these if you are to do development against this build)

GNUmakefile

```
global_cppflags := -ggdb -fno-exceptions -DBUILDING_CAIRO__ -DBUILDING_GTK__ \
         $(am__append_1) $(am__append_2)
#global_cppflags := -Wall -W -Wcast-align -Wchar-subscripts \
#       -Wreturn-type -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-format-y2k \
#       -Wundef -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wpointer-arith \
#       -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses \
#       -fno-exceptions -DBUILDING_CAIRO__ -DBUILDING_GTK__ \
#       $(am__append_1) $(am__append_2)
global_cflags := -ggdb
global_cxxflags := -ggdb -fno-rtti
```

Then to test that debugging symbols were include in the compiler and linker output I ran gdb as follows

```
~/dev/webkitgtk-2.0.4$ gdb ./Programs/MiniBrowser -d ./Tools/MiniBrowser/gtk/ 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.8-1ubuntu4) 7.8.0.20141001-cvs
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./Programs/MiniBrowser...done.
(gdb) l
188                                                         "WebKitSettings writable properties for default WebKitWebView",
189                                                         "WebKitSettings properties",
190                                                         webkitSettings,
191                                                         NULL);
192     g_option_group_add_entries(webSettingsGroup, optionEntries);
193     g_free(optionEntries);
194 
195     /* Option context takes ownership of the group. */
196     g_option_context_add_group(context, webSettingsGroup);
197 
(gdb) l
198     return TRUE;
199 }
200 
201 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
202 {
203     gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
204 
205     GOptionContext *context = g_option_context_new(NULL);
206     g_option_context_add_main_entries(context, commandLineOptions, 0);
207     g_option_context_add_group(context, gtk_get_option_group(TRUE));
(gdb)
```

Comment: I'll look at getting this working in eclipse later it would handy to do your debugging there.

Comment: I can't believe you did all that!!! I can't thank you enough, really. I'll wait 14 hours from now to accept your answer so I can give you a bonus

Comment: It was fun, I enjoyed doing it  I've downloaded Eclipse for c/c++ and will figure out getting the debugger working in that. Should be doable.

Comment: It won't let me give you the bounty right now, apparently I have to wait 24 hours, I am about to try this, thanks!

Comment: Cool let me know how you get on.